# Google Calendar API - access other users google calendar via service account without manual authentication

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to be able to access other users Google Calendars through a service account so I am not prompted for authorization. I am doing this in a simple .net c# console app. When I attempt to create my credentials in the Google API Manager, it gives me the following alert when I specify I am using a non UI app and I want to access User Data. Isn't the purpose of using the service account to access other users data without a UI?

"**User data cannot be accessed from a platform without a UI because it requires user interaction for sign-in.**"

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood the meaning of using a service account to impersonate a user. To help you with Authentication, you might want to check this tutorial : [Google Calendar API Authentication](http://www.daimto.com/google-calendar-api-authentication-with-c/) with C# by Daimto.

Things to take note of :

- To be able to access other calendars by service account, users who own the calendar should share it to the service account.
- To impersonate a user, you must know the email address.

From the tutorial:

> - If you are only accessing data that you own there is no reason to ask a user for permission to access it. You can use a Service account. (**Privacy**)
> - If you want to be able to access data owned by someone else you will need to be [authenticated](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth).

Hope this helps!